# Edimax EW-7822UAC - Cannot get it working on my ArchLinux Server

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, arch-linux, wifi-driver

I cannot seem to get this new USB device running on my server

sudo make install says

> user@home rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517]$ make install
>
> install -p -m 644 8812au.ko  /lib/modules/3.11.4-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
>
> install: cannot stat ‘8812au.ko’: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: What is 8812au.ko? Can you try the command with the full path of the file?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/1on9hd/edimax_ew7822uac_cannot_get_it_working_on_my/